# Evaluate $\int{\frac{1}{x^3}}$ using u-sub.

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, substitution

I tried solving $\int{\frac{1}{x^3}}$ using u-sub instead of power rule and I got $-\frac{1}{2}x^{-2}$ instead of $\frac{x^4}{4}$. Its very possible I've made a very simple mistake or their is something fundamentally wrong with my idea, if someone could show how/if this problem can be done with u-sub it would be greatly appreciated. My work to solve the problem are as follows:
$$
\int{\frac{1}{x^3}dx}
\\u=x^3
\\x=u^{1/3}
\\du=3x^{2}dx
\\dx=\frac{1}{3x^2}du
\\\int{\frac{1}{u}\times{\frac{1}{3x^2}du}}
\\\int{\frac{1}{u}\times{\frac{1}{3u^{2/3}}du}}
\\\int{u^{-1}\times{\frac{1}{3}\times{u^{-2/3}}}du}
\\\frac{1}{3}\int{u^{-1}\times{{u^{-2/3}}}du}
\\\frac{1}{3}\int{u^{-1+-2/3}du}
\\\frac{1}{3}\int{u^{-5/3}du}
\\\frac{1}{3}\times{\frac{u^{\frac{-5}{3}+1}}{\frac{-5}{3}+1}}
\\\frac{1}{3}\times{\frac{u^{\frac{-2}{3}}}{\frac{-2}{3}}}
\\\frac{1}{3}\times{\frac{3}{-2}}\times{u^{\frac{-2}{3}}}
\\-\frac{1}{2}\times{u^{\frac{-2}{3}}}
\\-\frac{1}{2}\times{x^{3^{\frac{-2}{3}}}}
\\-\frac{1}{2}\times{x^{\frac{-6}{2}}}
\\-\frac{1}{2}x^{-2}
$$

Comment: You can verify which is the correct answer by differentiation

Comment: On your one before last line, you should have $x ^ \frac{-6}{3}$ (instead of $x ^ \frac{-6}{2}$)

Comment: An easier substitution is $u=\frac 1x.$ Then $du =\frac{-dx}{x^2}$ and you get that you are seeking: $$-\int u\,du=-\frac 12 u^2=-\frac 12\frac1{x^2}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Remember that $$\frac{1}{x^3} = x^{-3}$$
So actually  by the power rule you'd have:

$$\int x^{-3}dx = \frac{x^{-3+1}}{-3+1}+C  = -\frac{1}{2}x^{-2}+C$$

So you are correct with your solution

Comment: My mistake was comparing my answer to the answer of a different problem, $\int{x^{3}}$. Thanks for double checking my work.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is fine maybe there is a typo in your textbook.

Also an easier u-sub would be letting $u=\frac{1}{x}
$ then $du=-\frac{1}{x^2} dx
$

and then notice $\frac{1}
{x^3} = \frac{1}{x^2} \cdot \frac{1}{x}$

So the integral becomes $\int (-u) du = -\frac{u^2}{2}+C  $

and after subbing $u $ back you get $-\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{x^2}= -\frac{1}{2}\cdot x^{-2}$